# Encoded video made using the Nvidia encoded SDK is not correct

Tags: c++, c, nvidia

I am trying to integrate the Nvidia Encoder SDK with the Nvidia Frame Buffer Capture SDK. I am capturing frames in a cuda buffer and then sending then to the Nvidia Encoder to be encoded in H.264 format.
The encoded video however, is not what I want it to be, it is a completely pink screen.
Are there any reasons as to why it might be happening?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
#include"nvEncodeAPI.h"
#include <NvFBC.h>
// If you have the CUDA Toolkit Installed, you can include the CUDA headers
// #include "cuda.h"
//#include "cuda_drvapi_dynlink_cuda.h"
#include"cuda.h"

#include "NvFBCUtils.h"

#define APP_VERSION 4

#define LIB_NVFBC_NAME "libnvidia-fbc.so.1"
#define LIB_CUDA_NAME  "libcuda.so.1"

#define N_FRAMES 10
/*
 * CUDA entry points
 */
typedef CUresult (* CUINITPROC) (unsigned int Flags);
typedef CUresult (* CUDEVICEGETPROC) (CUdevice *device, int ordinal);
typedef CUresult (* CUCTXCREATEV2PROC) (CUcontext *pctx, unsigned int flags, CUdevice dev);
typedef CUresult (* CUMEMCPYDTOHV2PROC) (void *dstHost, CUdeviceptr srcDevice, size_t ByteCount);
typedef CUresult (* CUGETDEVICEPTR) (CUdeviceptr *dptr, size_t bytesize);

static CUINITPROC cuInit_ptr = NULL;
static CUDEVICEGETPROC cuDeviceGet_ptr = NULL;
static CUCTXCREATEV2PROC cuCtxCreate_v2_ptr = NULL;
static CUMEMCPYDTOHV2PROC cuMemcpyDtoH_v2_ptr = NULL;
static CUGETDEVICEPTR cuGetDevicePtr=NULL;


typedef NVENCSTATUS (*PNVENCCREATEINSTANCE) (NV_ENCODE_API_FUNCTION_LIST* pFuncList);

/**
 * Dynamically opens the CUDA library and resolves the symbols that are
 * needed for this application.
 *
 * \param [out] libCUDA
 *   A pointer to the opened CUDA library.
 *
 * \return
 *   NVFBC_TRUE in case of success, NVFBC_FALSE otherwise.
 */
static NVFBC_BOOL cuda_load_library(void *libCUDA)
{
    libCUDA = dlopen(LIB_CUDA_NAME, RTLD_NOW);
    if (libCUDA == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s'\n", LIB_CUDA_NAME);
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuInit_ptr = (CUINITPROC) dlsym(libCUDA, "cuInit");
    if (cuInit_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'cuInit'\n");
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuDeviceGet_ptr = (CUDEVICEGETPROC) dlsym(libCUDA, "cuDeviceGet");
    if (cuDeviceGet_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'cuDeviceGet'\n");
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuCtxCreate_v2_ptr = (CUCTXCREATEV2PROC) dlsym(libCUDA, "cuCtxCreate_v2");
    if (cuCtxCreate_v2_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'cuCtxCreate_v2'\n");
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuMemcpyDtoH_v2_ptr = (CUMEMCPYDTOHV2PROC) dlsym(libCUDA, "cuMemcpyDtoH_v2");
    if (cuMemcpyDtoH_v2_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'cuMemcpyDtoH_v2'\n");
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuGetDevicePtr = (CUGETDEVICEPTR) dlsym(libCUDA,"cuMemAlloc");

    if(cuGetDevicePtr==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'cuMemAlloc'\n");
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    return NVFBC_TRUE;
}

/**
 * Initializes CUDA and creates a CUDA context.
 *
 * \param [in] cuCtx
 *   A pointer to the created CUDA context.
 *
 * \return
 *   NVFBC_TRUE in case of success, NVFBC_FALSE otherwise.
 */
static NVFBC_BOOL cuda_init(CUcontext *cuCtx)
{
    CUresult cuRes;
    CUdevice cuDev;

    cuRes = cuInit_ptr(0);
    if (cuRes != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize CUDA (result: %d)\n", cuRes);
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuRes = cuDeviceGet_ptr(&cuDev, 0);
    if (cuRes != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to get CUDA device (result: %d)\n", cuRes);
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    cuRes = cuCtxCreate_v2_ptr(cuCtx, CU_CTX_SCHED_AUTO, cuDev);
    if (cuRes != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create CUDA context (result: %d)\n", cuRes);
        return NVFBC_FALSE;
    }

    return NVFBC_TRUE;
}


/**
 * Initializes the NvFBC and CUDA libraries and creates an NvFBC instance.
 *
 * Creates and sets up a capture session to video memory using the CUDA interop.
 *
 * Captures a bunch of frames every second, converts them to BMP and saves them
 * to the disk.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //handing the opening of the nvidia encoder library
    void* handle = dlopen("libnvidia-encode.so",RTLD_NOW);

    if(handle==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to load the nvidia encoder library");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    PNVENCCREATEINSTANCE NvEncCreateInstance_ptr;

    NvEncCreateInstance_ptr = (PNVENCCREATEINSTANCE) dlsym(handle,"NvEncodeAPICreateInstance");

    if(NvEncCreateInstance_ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Failure to load the nv encode lib");
    }


    static struct option longopts[] = {
        { "get-status", no_argument, NULL, 'g' },
        { "track", required_argument, NULL, 't' },
        { "frames", required_argument, NULL, 'f' },
        { "size", required_argument, NULL, 's' },
        { "format", required_argument, NULL, 'o' },
        { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 }
    };

    int opt, ret;
    unsigned int i, nFrames = N_FRAMES;
    NVFBC_SIZE frameSize = { 0, 0 };
    NVFBC_BOOL printStatusOnly = NVFBC_FALSE;

    NVFBC_TRACKING_TYPE trackingType = NVFBC_TRACKING_DEFAULT;
    char outputName[NVFBC_OUTPUT_NAME_LEN];
    uint32_t outputId = 0;

    void *libNVFBC = NULL, *libCUDA = NULL;
    PNVFBCCREATEINSTANCE NvFBCCreateInstance_ptr = NULL;
    NVFBC_API_FUNCTION_LIST pFn;

    CUcontext cuCtx;

    NVFBCSTATUS fbcStatus;
    NVFBC_BOOL fbcBool;

    NVFBC_SESSION_HANDLE fbcHandle;
    NVFBC_CREATE_HANDLE_PARAMS createHandleParams;
    NVFBC_GET_STATUS_PARAMS statusParams;
    NVFBC_CREATE_CAPTURE_SESSION_PARAMS createCaptureParams;
    NVFBC_DESTROY_CAPTURE_SESSION_PARAMS destroyCaptureParams;
    NVFBC_DESTROY_HANDLE_PARAMS destroyHandleParams;
    NVFBC_TOCUDA_SETUP_PARAMS setupParams;

    NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT bufferFormat = NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT_NV12;

    char videoFile[64]="video.h264";

    FILE* fd;


    /*
     * Parse the command line.
     */
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "hgt:f:s:o:", longopts, NULL)) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'g':
                printStatusOnly = NVFBC_TRUE;
                break;
            case 't':
                NvFBCUtilsParseTrackingType(optarg, &trackingType, outputName);
                break;
            case 'f':
                nFrames = (unsigned int) atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 's':
                ret = sscanf(optarg, "%ux%u", &frameSize.w, &frameSize.h);
                if (ret != 2) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid size format: '%s'\n", optarg);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                break;
            case 'o':
                if (!strcasecmp(optarg, "rgb")) {
                    bufferFormat = NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT_RGB;
                } else if (!strcasecmp(optarg, "argb")) {
                    bufferFormat = NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ARGB;
                } else if (!strcasecmp(optarg, "nv12")) {
                    bufferFormat = NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT_NV12;
                } else if (!strcasecmp(optarg, "yuv444p")) {
                    bufferFormat = NVFBC_BUFFER_FORMAT_YUV444P;
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown buffer format: '%s'\n", optarg);
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                break;
            case 'h':
            default:
                usage(argv[0]);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }

    NvFBCUtilsPrintVersions(APP_VERSION);

    /*
     * Dynamically load the NvFBC library.
     */
    libNVFBC = dlopen(LIB_NVFBC_NAME, RTLD_NOW);
    if (libNVFBC == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s'\n", LIB_NVFBC_NAME);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fbcBool = cuda_load_library(libCUDA);
    if (fbcBool != NVFBC_TRUE) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fbcBool = cuda_init(&cuCtx);
    if (fbcBool != NVFBC_TRUE) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

         //input output buffer the contains all the pointers to the functions for the api
    NV_ENCODE_API_FUNCTION_LIST nvencFunctionList;

    nvencFunctionList.version=NV_ENCODE_API_FUNCTION_LIST_VER;

    //this function call populates the passed pointer to the nvidia api function list with
    //the function pointers to the routines implemented by the encoder api
    NVENCSTATUS status = NvEncCreateInstance_ptr(&nvencFunctionList);//NvEncodeAPICreateInstance(&nvencFunctionList);

    //exit code if failed to create instance of the api
    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("The nvidia encoder could not be initialized");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //creating the encode session params
    NV_ENC_OPEN_ENCODE_SESSION_EX_PARAMS openSessionExParams;

    //initializing them and then adding the values
    // memset(&openSessionExParams,0,sizeof(openSessionExParams));

    //setting the version
    openSessionExParams.version = NV_ENC_OPEN_ENCODE_SESSION_EX_PARAMS_VER;
    openSessionExParams.deviceType = NV_ENC_DEVICE_TYPE_CUDA;
    //Note -  Maybe change the next line
    //ading the device pointer which in this case will be a cuda context
    openSessionExParams.device = (void*)cuCtx;

    openSessionExParams.reserved = NULL;

    openSessionExParams.apiVersion = NVENCAPI_VERSION;

    //setting all values of the reserved 1 array to 0
    //Note - check the next two lines
    memset(openSessionExParams.reserved1,0,253*sizeof(uint32_t));//sizeof(openSessionExParams.reserved1)/sizeof(openSessionExParams.reserved1[0]));

    memset(openSessionExParams.reserved2,NULL,64*sizeof(void*));//sizeof(openSessionExParams.reserved2)/sizeof(openSessionExParams.reserved2[0]));

    //handle for the encoder
    void* encoder;
    //Note- Seg fault
    status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncOpenEncodeSessionEx(&openSessionExParams,&encoder);
    //NvEncOpenEncodeSessionEx(&openSessionExParams,encoder);   

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failure opening encoding session: %u\n",status);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //getting the count of the available encoder settings
    uint32_t guidCount;

    status =nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodeGUIDCount(encoder,&guidCount);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failure getting GUID count");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //allocating a buffer that holds that count
    GUID* GUIDs = malloc(guidCount*sizeof(GUID));

    //number of supported guid
    uint32_t supportedGUID;

    //adding all the guids to the previously allocated buffer
    status =nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodeGUIDs(encoder,GUIDs,guidCount,&supportedGUID);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failure filling the guid buffer");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //setting the encode guid
    GUID encodeGuid = NV_ENC_CODEC_H264_GUID;

    //settin up the presets
    uint32_t encodePresetCount;

    status =nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodePresetCount(encoder,encodeGuid,&encodePresetCount);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failure getting the encoder preset count");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //allocating a buffer to hold the suppoting preset guid
    GUID *presetGUIDs = malloc(encodePresetCount*sizeof(GUID));

    uint32_t supportedPresetGUIDs;


    status =nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodePresetGUIDs(encoder,encodeGuid,presetGUIDs,encodePresetCount,&supportedPresetGUIDs);
    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failure filling up the preset buffer");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //getting a preset guid Note - check this line later
    GUID presetGuid = NV_ENC_PRESET_LOW_LATENCY_HQ_GUID;

    //setting up a preset congif Note - check this
    NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG encPresetConfig;

    encPresetConfig.version = NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG_VER;
    encPresetConfig.presetCfg.version=NV_ENC_CONFIG_VER;

    status =  nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodePresetConfig(encoder,encodeGuid,presetGuid,&encPresetConfig);


    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error getting the preset configuration");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //getting the input format which is YUV for our solution

    //retrieving the input formats
    uint32_t inputFormatCount;
    status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetInputFormatCount(encoder,encodeGuid,&inputFormatCount);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error getting the input buffer format count");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //allocating a buffer for the input formats
    NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT* encodeBufferFormats = malloc(inputFormatCount*sizeof(encodeBufferFormats));
    //holding the size of the supported formats
    uint32_t supportedInputFormats;

    //filling up the above buffer
    status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetInputFormats(encoder,encodeGuid, encodeBufferFormats,inputFormatCount,&supportedInputFormats);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error getting the supported input formats");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //selecting a buffer format
    //NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT bufferFormat = NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_IYUV;

    //querying the underlying hardware encoder capabilities can be done using the API

    //initializing the hardware encoder

    NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS initializationParams;


    /* NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG presetConfig;
    presetConfig.version = NV_ENC_PRESET_CONFIG_VER;



    NV_ENC_CONFIG encoderConfig;

    encoderConfig.version = NV_ENC_CONFIG_VER;
    encoderConfig.profileGUID=NV_ENC_CODEC_PROFILE_AUTOSELECT_GUID;


    presetConfig.presetCfg=encoderConfig;
    status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncGetEncodePresetConfig(encoder,encodeGuid,presetGuid,&presetConfig);*/

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to get preset config %u",status);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    //initializing the encoder params
    initializationParams.version = NV_ENC_INITIALIZE_PARAMS_VER;
    initializationParams.encodeConfig = &encPresetConfig.presetCfg;
    initializationParams.encodeGUID = encodeGuid;
    initializationParams.presetGUID=presetGuid;
    initializationParams.encodeWidth = 600;
    initializationParams.encodeHeight = 600;
    initializationParams.frameRateNum = 60;
    initializationParams.frameRateDen = 1;
    initializationParams.enablePTD=1;

    status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncInitializeEncoder(encoder,&initializationParams);

    if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error initializing encoder, %u",status);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }    

    //allocating the nvidia input output buffers
    int num_macroblocks = ((600 + 15) / 16) * ((600 + 15) / 16);
    int max_surfaces = (num_macroblocks >= 8160) ? 16 : 32;
    NV_ENC_INPUT_PTR* inputBuffers = (NV_ENC_INPUT_PTR*) malloc(max_surfaces * sizeof(NV_ENC_INPUT_PTR));
    NV_ENC_OUTPUT_PTR* outputBuffers = (NV_ENC_OUTPUT_PTR*) malloc(max_surfaces * sizeof(NV_ENC_OUTPUT_PTR));
    //CUdeviceptr* cudaDevicePtrs = (CUdeviceptr*) malloc(max_surfaces*sizeof(CUdeviceptr));


    for(int i=0;i<max_surfaces;i++)
    {

    //creating the input buffer
        NV_ENC_CREATE_INPUT_BUFFER inputBufferParams;
        inputBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_CREATE_INPUT_BUFFER_VER;
        inputBufferParams.width =(600 + 31) & ~31;
        inputBufferParams.height=(600 + 31) & ~31;
        inputBufferParams.bufferFmt = NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_IYUV;
        inputBufferParams.reserved=0;
        memset(inputBufferParams.reserved1,0,57*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(inputBufferParams.reserved2,NULL,63*sizeof(void*));

        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncCreateInputBuffer(encoder,&inputBufferParams);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Input buffer could not be created");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        //creating the output buffer

        NV_ENC_CREATE_BITSTREAM_BUFFER bitstreamBufferParams;
        bitstreamBufferParams.version = NV_ENC_CREATE_BITSTREAM_BUFFER_VER;
         bitstreamBufferParams.reserved=0;
        memset(bitstreamBufferParams.reserved1,0,58*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(bitstreamBufferParams.reserved2,NULL,64*sizeof(void*));


        //This line is giving me the error, NV_ENC_ERR_UNIMPLEMENTED
        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncCreateBitstreamBuffer(encoder,&bitstreamBufferParams);

         if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Bitstream could not be created %i",status);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        /* CUresult cuResult = cuGetDevicePtr(&cudaDevicePtrs[i],600);

        if(cuResult!=CUDA_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Could not allocate cuda device pointer, %u\n",cuResult);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }*/

        inputBuffers[i]=inputBufferParams.inputBuffer;
        outputBuffers[i]=bitstreamBufferParams.bitstreamBuffer;
    }

    /*
     * Resolve the 'NvFBCCreateInstance' symbol that will allow us to get
     * the API function pointers.
     */
    NvFBCCreateInstance_ptr =
        (PNVFBCCREATEINSTANCE) dlsym(libNVFBC, "NvFBCCreateInstance");
    if (NvFBCCreateInstance_ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to resolve symbol 'NvFBCCreateInstance'\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Create an NvFBC instance.
     *
     * API function pointers are accessible through pFn.
     */
    memset(&pFn, 0, sizeof(pFn));

    pFn.dwVersion = NVFBC_VERSION;

    fbcStatus = NvFBCCreateInstance_ptr(&pFn);
    if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create NvFBC instance (status: %d)\n",
                fbcStatus);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Create a session handle that is used to identify the client.
     */
    memset(&createHandleParams, 0, sizeof(createHandleParams));

    createHandleParams.dwVersion = NVFBC_CREATE_HANDLE_PARAMS_VER;

    fbcStatus = pFn.nvFBCCreateHandle(&fbcHandle, &createHandleParams);
    if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pFn.nvFBCGetLastErrorStr(fbcHandle));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Get information about the state of the display driver.
     *
     * This call is optional but helps the application decide what it should
     * do.
     */
    memset(&statusParams, 0, sizeof(statusParams));

    statusParams.dwVersion = NVFBC_GET_STATUS_PARAMS_VER;

    fbcStatus = pFn.nvFBCGetStatus(fbcHandle, &statusParams);
    if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pFn.nvFBCGetLastErrorStr(fbcHandle));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (printStatusOnly) {
        NvFBCUtilsPrintStatus(&statusParams);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (statusParams.bCanCreateNow == NVFBC_FALSE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "It is not possible to create a capture session "
                        "on this system.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (trackingType == NVFBC_TRACKING_OUTPUT) {
        if (!statusParams.bXRandRAvailable) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The XRandR extension is not available.\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "It is therefore not possible to track an RandR output.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        outputId = NvFBCUtilsGetOutputId(statusParams.outputs,
                                         statusParams.dwOutputNum,
                                         outputName);
        if (outputId == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "RandR output '%s' not found.\n", outputName);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Create a capture session.
     */
    printf("Creating an asynchronous capture session of %u frames with 1 "
           "second internal between captures.\n", nFrames);

    memset(&createCaptureParams, 0, sizeof(createCaptureParams));

    createCaptureParams.dwVersion     = NVFBC_CREATE_CAPTURE_SESSION_PARAMS_VER;
    createCaptureParams.eCaptureType  = NVFBC_CAPTURE_SHARED_CUDA;
    createCaptureParams.bWithCursor   = NVFBC_TRUE;
    createCaptureParams.frameSize     = frameSize;
    createCaptureParams.eTrackingType = trackingType;

    if (trackingType == NVFBC_TRACKING_OUTPUT) {
        createCaptureParams.dwOutputId = outputId;
    }

    fbcStatus = pFn.nvFBCCreateCaptureSession(fbcHandle, &createCaptureParams);
    if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pFn.nvFBCGetLastErrorStr(fbcHandle));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Set up the capture session.
     */
    memset(&setupParams, 0, sizeof(setupParams));

    setupParams.dwVersion     = NVFBC_TOCUDA_SETUP_PARAMS_VER;
    setupParams.eBufferFormat = bufferFormat;

    fbcStatus = pFn.nvFBCToCudaSetUp(fbcHandle, &setupParams);
    if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pFn.nvFBCGetLastErrorStr(fbcHandle));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * We are now ready to start grabbing frames.
     */

    fd = fopen(videoFile, "wb");
    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create '%s'\n", videoFile);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }



    //configuring the per frame encode parameters
    NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS encoderPicParams;

    //Codec specific params
    /* NV_ENC_CODEC_PIC_PARAMS h264Params;

    h264Params.h264PicParams.reserved3=0;
    h264Params.h264PicParams.reservedBitFields=0;
    h264Params.h264PicParams.ltrUsageMode=0;
    memset(h264Params.h264PicParams.reserved,0,242*sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(h264Params.h264PicParams.reserved2,NULL,61*sizeof(void*));*/

    encoderPicParams.version = NV_ENC_PIC_PARAMS_VER;
    //encoderPicParams.codecPicParams=h264Params;
    encoderPicParams.inputWidth=(600+ 31) & ~31;
    encoderPicParams.inputHeight=(600+ 31) & ~31;
    encoderPicParams.inputPitch = (600+ 31) & ~31;
    //encoderPicParams.encodePicFlags=NV_ENC_PIC_FLAG_FORCEIDR;
    //encoderPicParams.bufferFmt=NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_IYUV;
    encoderPicParams.pictureStruct=NV_ENC_PIC_STRUCT_FRAME;

    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        static CUdeviceptr cuDevicePtr;
        static unsigned char *frame = NULL;
        static uint32_t lastByteSize = 0;

        //char filename[64];

        int index=i;
        if(i>=max_surfaces)
        {
            index=i%max_surfaces;
        }

        int res;
        uint64_t t1, t2, t1_total, t2_total, t_delta, wait_time_ms;

        CUresult cuRes;

        NVFBC_TOCUDA_GRAB_FRAME_PARAMS grabParams;

        NVFBC_FRAME_GRAB_INFO frameInfo;

        t1 = NvFBCUtilsGetTimeInMillis();
        t1_total = t1;

        memset(&grabParams, 0, sizeof(grabParams));
        memset(&frameInfo, 0, sizeof(frameInfo));

        grabParams.dwVersion = NVFBC_TOCUDA_GRAB_FRAME_PARAMS_VER;

        /*
         * Use asynchronous calls.
         *
         * The application will not wait for a new frame to be ready.  It will
         * capture a frame that is already available.  This might result in
         * capturing several times the same frame.  This can be detected by
         * checking the frameInfo.bIsNewFrame structure member.
         */
        grabParams.dwFlags = NVFBC_TOCUDA_GRAB_FLAGS_NOWAIT;

        /*
         * This structure will contain information about the captured frame.
         */
        grabParams.pFrameGrabInfo = &frameInfo;

        /*
         * The frame will be mapped in video memory through this CUDA
         * device pointer.
         */
        grabParams.pCUDADeviceBuffer = &cuDevicePtr;

        /*
         * Capture a frame.
         */
        fbcStatus = pFn.nvFBCToCudaGrabFrame(fbcHandle, &grabParams);
        if (fbcStatus != NVFBC_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", pFn.nvFBCGetLastErrorStr(fbcHandle));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        t2 = NvFBCUtilsGetTimeInMillis();

        /*
         * Allocate or re-allocate the destination buffer in system memory
         * when necessary.
         *
         * This is to handle change of resolution.
         */
        if (lastByteSize < frameInfo.dwByteSize) {
            frame = (unsigned char *)realloc(frame, frameInfo.dwByteSize);
            if (frame == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate system memory\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            printf("Reallocated %u KB of system memory\n",
                   frameInfo.dwByteSize / 1024);

            lastByteSize = frameInfo.dwByteSize;
        }

        printf("%s id %u grabbed in %llu ms",
               (frameInfo.bIsNewFrame ? "New frame" : "Frame"),
               frameInfo.dwCurrentFrame,
               (unsigned long long) (t2 - t1));

        /*
         * Download frame from video memory to system memory.
         */
        t1 = NvFBCUtilsGetTimeInMillis();

        cuRes = cuMemcpyDtoH_v2_ptr((void *) frame, cuDevicePtr,
                                    frameInfo.dwByteSize);
        if (cuRes != CUDA_SUCCESS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "CUDA memcpy failure (result: %d)\n", cuRes);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        //creating the params for the nv enc lock input buffer
        //inputBufferParams.pSysMemBuffer=(void*) frame;

        //status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncCreateInputBuffer(encoder,&inputBufferParams);
        //setting up the input params

        NV_ENC_REGISTER_RESOURCE registerResource;
        registerResource.version=NV_ENC_REGISTER_RESOURCE_VER;
        registerResource.resourceType = NV_ENC_INPUT_RESOURCE_TYPE_CUDADEVICEPTR;
        registerResource.width = (600+31)&~31;
        registerResource.height=(600+31)&~31;
        registerResource.pitch=(600+31)&~31;
        registerResource.resourceToRegister = (void*)cuDevicePtr;
        registerResource.bufferFormat = NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_NV12;

        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncRegisterResource(encoder,&registerResource);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Failed to register resource, %u",status);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        //mapping these resources
        NV_ENC_MAP_INPUT_RESOURCE mappedResource;

        mappedResource.version = NV_ENC_MAP_INPUT_RESOURCE_VER;
        mappedResource.registeredResource=registerResource.registeredResource;

        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncMapInputResource(encoder,&mappedResource);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Could not map resource: %u,",status);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }




        encoderPicParams.outputBitstream=outputBuffers[index];
        encoderPicParams.inputBuffer=mappedResource.mappedResource;
        encoderPicParams.bufferFmt=mappedResource.mappedBufferFmt;
        /* memset(encoderPicParams.reserved1,0,6*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(encoderPicParams.reserved2,NULL,2*sizeof(void*));
        memset(encoderPicParams.reserved3,0,286*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(encoderPicParams.reserved4,0,60*sizeof(void*));*/

        //sending the picture to be encoded
        status=nvencFunctionList.nvEncEncodePicture(encoder,&encoderPicParams);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("\n Unable to encode video, Error code: %u",status);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        //setting up the lock bitstream params

        //sending the data to the output stream
        NV_ENC_LOCK_BITSTREAM lockBitstreamParams;
        lockBitstreamParams.version=NV_ENC_LOCK_BITSTREAM_VER;
        lockBitstreamParams.doNotWait=0;
        lockBitstreamParams.outputBitstream=outputBuffers[index];
        lockBitstreamParams.reservedBitFields=0;
        memset(lockBitstreamParams.reserved,0,219*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(lockBitstreamParams.reserved1,0,13*sizeof(uint32_t));
        memset(lockBitstreamParams.reserved2,NULL,64*sizeof(uint32_t));

        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncLockBitstream(encoder,&lockBitstreamParams);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("error locking bitstream");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        //writing the video data to the file
        int bytes = fwrite(lockBitstreamParams.bitstreamBufferPtr,1,lockBitstreamParams.bitstreamSizeInBytes ,fd);


        printf("\nNumber of bytes: %u\n",bytes);

        if(bytes==0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to write to '%s'\n", videoFile);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncUnlockBitstream(encoder,outputBuffers[index]);


        status = nvencFunctionList.nvEncUnmapInputResource(encoder,mappedResource.mappedResource);

        if(status!=NV_ENC_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("failure to map resource, %u",status);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```